# AVR 60Hz periodic interrupt

Tags: microcontroller, avr, frequency, timer, counter

How can I configure an AVR microcontroller timer to generate periodic interrupt events at 60 Hz rate, using 14.745 MHz system clock?

Comment: What clock frequency is the micro using and why not divide down the clock frequency and save the micro's resources for something more important?

Comment: @Andy aka   Thanks for your comment . I just want to access  60Hz frequency by using microcontrollers AVR and timer counters . Please help me with this problem?

Comment: repeating the same question doesn't help provide more clarity. maybe it can be done, or maybe not. can't determine without more information. timing information depends on the master clock frequency, which you have not shared with us.

Comment: @MarkU ok I got it . Sorry  . I want to use a XTAL (14.745 MHz ) . How can do this?

Comment: Edited your post to include the information in the comments, updated the title, hopefully this will help get you an answer.

Comment: @Marku I appreciate you for your answer .  Let me tell you that I want to use timer/counters of an AVR Micro Controllers to access 60hz frequency with 14,750 MHz crystal. I think is that different .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 14,745,000 / 60 = 245,750 counts of the 14.745MHz system clock per 60Hz cycle. So what you need to do is somehow divide down that system clock.

As @AndyAka suggested in the comments, you could use a 18-bit hardware counter to divide the 14.745MHz system clock by 245,750 (hexadecimal 0x3bff6 or binary 0011_1011_1111_1111_0110) to get a 60Hz output in hardware, then use that to drive the interrupt input pin. This approach interrupts the microcontroller at a 60Hz rate, leaving the microcontroller free to perform other tasks.

Alternatively, if you can't add external hardware, but can tolerate some reduced software performance, the internal hardware timer/counter could be used. Unfortunately, the required divisor 245,750 exceeds the limit of a 16-bit hardware timer counter, so a 60Hz periodic interrupt rate can't be achieved directly. However, you could configure the timer for its slowest possible periodic interrupt that is a multiple of 60Hz. Then, use a software counter to further divide down to reach 60Hz event handling rate.

AVR ATmega328 datasheet: http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf

See section 12. Interrupts

See sections 15-18 about the various Timer/Counter modules built into the ATmega328.